# Drupal 8 hierarchy of content types with taxonomy as parent

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-content-types, drupal-contextual-filters

What would be the best way to implement a hierarchical structure like this:

- (A) Taxonomy term from single vocabulary

  - (B) Some content type with parent of type A

    - (C) Some content type with parent of type B

There are reference fields from (B) to (A) and from (C) to (B) but not from (C) to (A).

Basically i need to implement something like this:

```
Topic (taxonomy term)
|___ Subtopic (custom content type)
         |___ Page (custom content type)
         |___ Page (custom content type)
         |___ + N
|___ Subtopic (custom content type)
         |___ Page (custom content type)
         |___ Page (custom content type)
         |___ + N
```

I tried using entity reference in all flavours but with not much success. I don't know how to:

- Implement path aliasing when i add content of type (C) so i have hostname/(A)/(B)/(C) so i 
  don't have to enter the url manually (tried with url patterns but couldn't do it)
- Create a view that displays content belonging to (C) with `Context Filters` on `hostname/(A)/(B)/(C)` url

Any help is much appreciated!